# Valid json dont work with ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, json, angularjs-ng-repeat

My response from Java `servlet` via Angular, the request content is `text/html`
and I used `data.split`:

```
d = response.data.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, ''); // remove /r/n
data = d.split(" ");
for(var i =0 ; i<data.length; i++){
  data[i] = '{' + data[i] + '}'; // add {} to each k.v
}
```

The result looks like:

```
["{key:myKey,value:true}", "{key:myKey,value:true}"....]
```

And my HTML

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="line in fixedDBArray">
    {{line.key}} - {{line.value}} 
  </li>
</ul>
```

The anguler `data-binding` look like:

```
$scope.fixedDBArray = data //response.data
```

And `{{fixedDBArray}}` works fine but `{{line.key}}` and `{{line.value}}` do not work. I had checked http://jsonlint.com/ and the json is valid.
Anyone knows what is the problem?

Comment: Something wrong in server code. It is wrapping each object in quotes that shouldn't be there. It is valid JSON , but instead of array of objects you have array of strings

Comment: No, I did it in js, the server returns a simple string with quotes at the start and end.

Comment: Server should be returning valid json, with desired structure, either way. Show more code of your transformation

Comment: No, the request is 'text/html' for Internal causes. posting more transformation code.

Comment: Structure is still wrong. Not enough information in question to fix this. Should be fixed at server

Comment: server sending wrong format code. Ask backend guy to correct it

Comment: The correct format would be [{"key":"myKey","value":"true"}, {"key":"myKey","value:"true"}] for the angularjs to work on ng-repeat

Comment: I'm the backend guy(need to fix this on the front-end)... anyone know hot to turn it to an object that ng-repeat can work with?

Comment: Why can't you serialize the data to json at server?

Comment: Cant use libs like Gson, company rules.

Comment: Then at least quote the keys and values properly so you can use JSON.parse()

Comment: No, cant use 3rd party jars.

Comment: JSON.parse() is javascript in browser

Comment: trying and posting the answer.

Comment: No, I get 'Unexpected token 'k', k -  for key.

Comment: It simply boils down to ... you need to create proper json string with double quotes as per [JSON specifications](http://json.org/). Or send as csv perhaps and then parse to array in browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you still want to fix this as it stands now. you can use replace method and make the value valid JSON object. i made a sample implementation of this [here](http://jsbin.com/nexihakofu/edit?html,js,output)

make sure that you use more efficient regular expression for adding additional quotes.just posting it for your reference without considering performance or complexity.

Comment: Thank! that did the job!!